# Get the SQL Query from Views

Tags: views, database

I used feeds to import a csv file into a customized content types that have 12 fields. I managed to create a view and display as table.

Right now I'm trying to write some php code to output xml based on the parameters users passed in url, and I'm having a little trouble on building up the query on selecting all 12 field_data tables.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you are letting the users "define" the view using filters and then once this is done, you would like to take the views query, use that to query your database and then pass the data somewhere through xml?

Comment: You could try something like this to get the query to show in the message area of drupal:
`drupal_set_message('Query:'.$view->build_info['query']);`

Comment: I managed to create my own page using php to handle that. Thanks

Comment: I actually found in the advance setting that shows the query for the view. Thanks still